# Cannot get percentiles or value from Aggregation

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

[image]

The *parentSalaries* is a list of Buckets of size 1 and contains Aggregations of size 2, which are "precentials_salary" and "avg_salary".
I am trying to get the *percentiles* values (5.0, 25.0 etc) and the value under the "*average_salary*" aggregation. However, there is no function like "getValue" or "getPercentiles" for the Aggregation.

I can see the data but can not extract them.

The code that I have is as below;

```
private void doSomething(Aggregations aggregations) {
 //aggregations is the Aggregations from the SearchResponse
 Terms parentSalaryRatio = aggregations.get("parent_salary_ratio");
 if (parentSalaryRatio != null) {
            List<? extends Terms.Bucket> parentSalaries = parentSalaryRatio.getBuckets();
            getTotalAvgSalaries(parentSalaries);
        }
}

 private void getTotalAvgSalaries(List<? extends Terms.Bucket> parentSalaries) {
      Aggregations aggregations = parentSalaries.get(0).getAggregations();
      Aggregation precentials = aggregations.get("precentials_salary");
      Aggregation precentials = aggregations.get("avg_salary");

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to cast to `ParsedTDigestPercentiles` at the right place. Cannot tell exactly where without a sample app to reproduce.

Comment: Thank you! .. I used ParsedTDigestPercentiles and it worked. "ParsedTDigestPercentiles percentiles = aggregations.get("precentials_salary");" and then I was able to get the data using the percentile function. "double value = percentiles.percentile(5.0);". Still trying to figure out the way of getting the "value" out of "avg_salary".  They should have defined a function for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

found the issue;

I used *ParsedSingleValueNumericMetricsAggregation* to extract the "value" data. It has the *value()* function. The *ParsedAvg* can be used as well. It extends *ParsedSingleValueNumericMetricsAggregation*

And for the percentiles, I used *ParsedTDigestPercentiles* as P.J.Meisch suggested